# Can't reshape .npy array from 1D raw patches to 2D image patches

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

Need to reshape 1-d 2914 pxls per picture array to 2-d 62*47 array, from a dataset

tried to creative a patches variable with np.load attached and then using np.shape(62,47) on said variable, got a "tuple isnt callable error"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.shape` is not a function. It returns the shape of your array, which is a tuple. You need to use the `np.reshape` function.

```py
import numpy as np

pic = np.random.rand(2914)
print(f"Shape: {pic.shape}")

pic = np.reshape(pic, (62, 47))
print(f"Shape: {pic.shape}")

print(f"np.shape: {np.shape(pic)}")
print(f"type of np.shape: {type(np.shape(pic))}")
```